# Full shape received: [256, 256, 3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a model (U-Net) on RGB images with shape of ( 256, 256, 3) but when I fit the model I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_1144 is incompatible with the layer: 
: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [256, 256, 3].
```

And the following warning:

```
 WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 256, 256, 3) 
for input Tensor("input_83:0", shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32), but it
was called on an input with incompatible shape (256, 256, 3).
```

It seems that the "None" parameter is missing

This is the model code:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input( shape=( 256,256,3, ) )
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

#Contraction path
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
 
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
 
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
 
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c5)

#Expansive path 
u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)
 
u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)
 
u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)
 
u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)
 
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
 
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=256)
```

Comment: What is the shape of your data?

Comment: ( 256, 256, 3 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first line of code as follows.

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input( shape=( 256,256,3, ) )
```

to

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input( shape=X.shape[1:] )
```

Comment: error ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'```

Comment: maybe its a version problem ?

Comment: convert X into a `numpy` array using `np.array(X)` before feeding into the model.

Answer (score 0):

The model expects the input to be a 4D Tensor but you are passing in a 3D Tensor.

You would just need to reshape the input before passing it to the model:

```
x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=-1)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,256,3))
```

Another issue is that the output of the model is a CONV2D instead of a Dense layer with a sigmoid activation function:

```
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(c9)
c10 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu')(flatten)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))(c10)
```

Comment: not worked..... ```'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'```

Comment: ```ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 11
  y sizes: 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256, 256
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension. ```

Comment: @HMQ check the updated answer I need to apply it to `y` as well.

Comment: I did that already ```ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[3], expected a dimension of 1, got 3 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,256,256,3].```

Comment: @HMQ updated it again looks like you did not flatten the output and then pass it through a Dense layer with a sigmoid activation function.

Comment: @HMQ please accept and upvote my answer :)